# Does break point trap always mean program was run from the debugger?

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm analyzing a core file which says:

```
Program terminated with signal 5, Trace/breakpoint trap
```

From this line can I be sure this was due to program hitting a breakpoint under GDB?

Is there any scenario the above error is possible when it is NOT run under the debugger?

Comment: I have near 0 knowledge of Unix systems however I may add something here: a breakpoint is just a instruction to be processed by the CPU. When you set a breakpoint at an address, the debugger actually changes the code and insert a `int 3` instruction. When the CPU executes this `int 3` instruction it will generate an exception that, if running under a debug it will handle this exception, if not under debugging the process will crash as the exception would not be handled.

Comment: Presumambly the program could have executed `raise(SIGTRAP);` itself.

Comment: When and where is this error message thrown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the program need not have run under a debugger for this to happen.

Try running a program and then using `kill -n 5 myProgram` (or equivalently `kill -s SIGTRAP`). It will send a SIGTRAP signal to the program in question, which will most likely cause it to terminate. If it produced a core dump in the process then it would have the message you show.

Or, as mentioned in the comments, the program could have raised that signal itself.

Comment: Yes, it was sent by a monitoring process.

Comment: In addition, the program could have executed a trap instruction (e.g. `__asm__((int3))` on i386 and x86_64), which would cause the OS to raise `SIGTRAP`. This is often used as a debugging help for "can not happen" conditions.